# How to call PHP page with Javascript & jQuery when user clicks on a href link?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

In a PHP Project I have hyperlink :

```
<a href="addid.php?id='. $Id . '">| Name |</a>';
```

When a user click on the link I need to add the selected "id" to session

**addid.php Code :**

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['id'] = $_GET['id'];
```

I need to accomplish this without reloading the page (need to add the "id" to session in background).

How to call `addid.php` with Javascript & jQuery?

NOTE: I tried this code, but it does load the `addid.php` in browser

```
$('a').click(function(){
      $.ajax(); 
        return false; 
});
```

Comment: Not sure if that is really your best option...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give your link an id:

```
<a id="something" href="addid.php?id='. $Id . '">| Name |</a>';
```

and then you can easily refer to it:

```
$('a#something').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.get($(this).attr('href')); // no handler fire and forget
});
```

The code you tried is invalid - have a look at [the api](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) for the jquery function you're using. `url` is a mandatory argument.

Check using developer tools/firebug/whatever you have installed that the request is sent to the right place, and the response if what you expect.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('a').click(function(){
   $.get($(this).attr('href'));
   return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at jquery:

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

Use ajax and set the id as a parameter in the data string.